# Why since my latest Docker image build is libgdiplus not found when using OfficeOpenXML

Tags: docker, .net-core, alpine-linux

[image: List item]

- There was no error/issue with this as of last Docker image build on 10 Feb 2021.
- Only recently building new image on 12 Mar 2021 did the error start
  occurring.
- Docker image and application code related to creating excel file have not changed
- Docker file includes:

  - FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine
  - RUN apk add libgdiplus --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted
- Docker build command output shows above image layer adding libgdiplus is added from cache
- Have confirmed libgdiplus.so.0 is in /usr/lib directory of running container once deployed

Comment: I can tell you that there's been no update to the base image because .NET Core 2.2 has been out-of-support since Dec 2019. That base image hasn't been updated since that time.  So you're running on .NET bits that haven't been updated and also a version of Alpine that hasn't been serviced since that time. Would highly recommend moving to a supported version of .NET Core (2.1, 3.1, .NET 5).

Comment: Thanks @MattThalman. Yes we are currently finalising our testing to move to a supported version and hopefully that will be a fallback solution for the issue if no other solution exists. Unfortunately this is happening now so we cannot deploy any further changes until we finalise the move to a supported version and there is no guarantee that will fix it either. The strange thing is, as you said there have been no changes to the base image (the whole image up until our code is added is built from cache), so why the sudden error where it did not exist before?